# Data view updates timing out in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-views

I have written 3 queries to extract and store data from the Click, Open and Bounce views and I have set them to update so only the delta should be added.

When I set the update type to overwrite they work, but when I set them to update only they keep failing with a timeout message.

Can anyone tell me why the update would be timing out when the overwrite works perfectly and is dealing with much bigger amounts of data?

Query text below for the click query, but the others are all similar.

Primary keys on the DE are Event Date, URL, Subscriber ID and Job id as I only want one click on each link on each day for each job.

```
SELECT
c.AccountID 
,c.JobID
,c.SubscriberID
,c.SubscriberKey
,c.EventDate
,c.URL
,j.EmailID
,j.EmailName

From _Click c
INNER JOIN _Job as J on j.jobID = c.jobID
Where IsUnique ='True'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So with data views, they contain about 180 days worth of rolling data, this amount of data based on activities within a MC account can end up quite large over time.

Overwriting queries is always quicker because it does not require you to iterate through each matching record to perform an upsert.

In order to prevent timeouts you should add a WHERE clause that only pulls in the last day of engagement data because historical engagement data does not change, it is simply a log of data that just keeps getting appended, so in order for you to bring the delta data through for example,

If you were running your queries daily, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT
c.AccountID 
,c.JobID
,c.SubscriberID
,c.SubscriberKey
,c.EventDate
,c.URL
,j.EmailID
,j.EmailName

From _Click c
INNER JOIN _Job as J on j.jobID = c.jobID
Where IsUnique ='True' AND
CAST(EventDate AS Date) > CAST(DATEADD(dd, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Date)
```

This will allow you to retrieve delta data by only getting the last 1 day worth of data and updating your target data extension.

This approach is fast and easy.

Comment: it's better to make your date criteria sargable (keeping all of the functions on the right side of the conditional): `c.eventDate >= convert(date, getDate()-1) and c.eventDate < convert(date, getDate())`

Comment: @AdamSpriggs that also works and will improve the query further

Comment: Great, thanks Adam Spriggs and thechrishaddad. I will try adding that date condition now

Comment: @Clare let us know how you go :)

Comment: @Clare you also have the option to have a date range of a few days, which will prevent gaps in your data if the daily query was to ever fail or get skipped.

Comment: I had success on the click update. Initially it failed on primary key violation. So i removed one of the primary keys and now the click query update is working. But Open update keeps failing. I removed the primary keys and it won't update as a primary key is necessary. What is the best field to be the primary key as subscriberkey, jobID, etc are going to occur more than once? I tried a composite of event date, job id, subscriber id but it failed. When i checked the records that failed, the event date of the failed record was different to the existing record so not sure why it would violate.

Comment: SubscriberID is completely unique on data views so probably use that @Clare